ComplexUpset Plot: Specification of intersect not working - error `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns
I want to create an upset plot using the ComplexUpset package in R, but I keep getting the error data must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns whenever I try to specify the columns for the intersect argument if I do not kick out all variables which should not be included in the plot. What is the issue here? How can I specify the intersect argument correctly for a dataset with this structure?
Here is a minimum example of my code:
library(ComplexUpset)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  group = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A"),
  likes_Action = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  likes_Comedy = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  likes_Drama = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  likes_Thriller = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  likes_SciFi = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  likes_Horror = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  likes_Adventure = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  likes_Romance = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
)

colnames(data) <- c("user_id", "group", "Action", "Comedy", "Drama", "Thriller", "SciFi", "Horror", "Adventure", "Romance")

genre <- colnames(data[3:ncol(data)])
genre

data[genre] = data[genre] == 1

upset(
  data = movie_data, 
  intersect = genre
)

